Ignore drag mouse effect from parent of GoogleMap widget in flutter
I have a google map widget inside my program.
child: GoogleMap(
                  mapType: state.isSatellite ? MapType.hybrid : MapType.normal,
                  myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: LatLng(
                      widget.initialLocation.latitude,
                      widget.initialLocation.longitude,
                    ),
                    zoom: widget.zoom,
                  ),
                  tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
                  scrollGesturesEnabled: !widget.staticPosition,
                  gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>{
                    Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
                      () => EagerGestureRecognizer(),
                    ),
                  },
                  onCameraMove: (position) {
                    bloc.add(
                      SetLocation(location: (
                        latitude: position.target.latitude,
                        longitude: position.target.longitude,
                      )),
                    );
                  },
                  onCameraIdle: () {
                    if (widget.staticPosition) {
                      bloc.add(SetCameraPosition(widget.initialLocation));
                    }
                  },
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
                    _controller.complete(controller);
                    if (state.currentLocation.latitude != 0 &&
                        state.currentLocation.longitude != 0) {
                      await controller.animateCamera(
                        CameraUpdate.newLatLng(
                          LatLng(
                            state.currentLocation.latitude,
                            state.currentLocation.longitude,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),

Problem is this one is inside a singlechildscrollview , when I hold mouse and drag the position changes but also the page is dragged. I dont want the page to be dragged.Any ideas?
I tried AbsorbPointer() and IgnorePointer().

In the Google Map widget, you can customize the gestureRecognizers to avoid conflicts.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Can please provide code example?
